Why swim tracks not oval?
In many competitive sports based on speed, racing happens on oval tracks: running, track cycling, speed skating, horse racing, to name a few.  Swimming would seem to be the exception where tracks are purely linear, and swimmers need to turn in-place (more or less) when they reach the end of the pool.  Why is swimming different from the others?
Some reasons I could imagine: space (the pool would be too large to reduce the differences between inner and outer lanes), history, or turning being easier in swimming than in other sports.

I do not know the answer of your question exactly but in addition to the three hypothetical reasons you cited:

Space (the pool would be too large to reduce the differences between inner and outer lanes)
History
Turning being easier in swimming than in other sports.



What would you do with the central space of the oval? In France, we usually have a soccer field inside a track field. For an oval swimming pool, some ideas of what could be inside is a plongeoir or another linear swimming pool where sports like water-polo or synchronised natation are performed.
Cost. It seems much cheaper to build a linear swimming pool than an oval one.


All good reasons. I wonder how easily a swimmer could navigate the curves. I suspect it might be difficult for something like the butterfly.

You're probably right in your reasoning, but I'll add something else that was not brought up in the existing answer.
I'd tend to say that the primary reason race pools aren't circular is because it is more difficult to make a turn in water than on land. This is due to the different body maneuvers and higher resistance from the water itself. Olympic athletes would be able to overcome this if it had always been that way, but as was said in a comment, it would probably be much harder to turn while doing something like the butterfly.
